# Constrained Optimization in R - adding new constraint

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, constraints, mathematical-optimization

I want to add a constraint to my optimization.

**Setting:** I optimize parameters `b[]`  using given likelihood function  `lf[i] <-`. Inputs `v` and `a1inv` are given. As you see in the code below, the likelihood function uses `omegav` which is product of  `omegav <- s %*% t(s)` and matrix `s` results from the parameters `b[]`.

**Problem:** Using this code, I get random `b[]`'s that are optimising the likelihood function through `omegav`. What i need, however, are such `b[]`'s that will create a matrix `omegav` equal to a given matrix `omegaoptim`. After the optimization i want to have optimal `b[]` such that `s %*% t(s) = omegaoptim`.

I can also show my restrictions in following way: i know, for example, that `b[3]*b[2]+b[7]*b[6]=omegaoptim[3,2]` which is `0,1736304 = omegaoptim[3,2]` in my case. In this way, I can create 25 restrictions for each number of 5x5 matrix `omegaoptim`. (see all restrictions below)

My question is, how can I add these additional constraints into my optimization problem?

The function used for the likelihood optimization:

```
loglt <- function(b,v,a1inv) {
      t <- nrow(v)
      n <- ncol(v)
      lf <- rep(0, t)

      # Restriction for the s matrix
      s55 <- -(a1inv[4,4]*b[15])/a1inv[4,5]

      s   <-   matrix(c(b[1],    0,      0,      0,      0,  
                        b[2],   b[6],    0,      0,      0,
                        b[3],   b[7],   b[10],   0,      0,
                        b[4],   b[8],   b[11],  b[13], b[15],
                        b[5],   b[9],   b[12],  b[14],  s55), nrow=n, byrow=T)

        omegav <- s %*% t(s)

        for (i in seq(t)) {
        lf[i] <- -0.5*n*log(2*pi) - 0.5*log(det(omegav)) - 0.5*v[i,] %*% inv(omegav) %*% cbind(v[i,])    
      }
      return(lf)  
    }
```

P.s.: the given `omegaoptim` can be also defined as `omegaoptim <- t(v) %*% v/nrow(v)`

25 restrictions:

```
b[1]*b[1]==omegav[1,1]
b[1]*b[2]==omegav[1,2]
b[1]*b[3]==omegav[1,3]
b[1]*b[4]==omegav[1,4]
b[1]*b[5]==omegav[1,5]

b[2]*b[1]==omegav[2,1]
b[2]*b[2]+b[6]*b[6]==omegav[2,2]
b[2]*b[3]+b[6]*b[7]==omegav[2,3]
b[2]*b[4]+b[6]*b[8]==omegav[2,4]
b[2]*b[5]+b[6]*b[9]==omegav[2,5]

b[3]*b[1]==omegav[3,1]
b[3]*b[2]+b[7]*b[6]==omegav[3,2]
b[3]*b[3]+b[7]*b[7]+b[10]*b[10]==omegav[3,3]
b[3]*b[4]+b[7]*b[8]+b[10]*b[11]==omegav[3,4]
b[3]*b[5]+b[7]*b[9]+b[10]*b[12]==omegav[3,5]


b[4]*b[1]==omegav[4,1]
b[4]*b[2]+b[8]*b[6]==omegav[4,2]
b[4]*b[3]+b[8]*b[7]+b[11]*b[10]==omegav[4,3]
b[4]*b[4]+b[8]*b[8]+b[11]*b[11]+b[13]*b[13]+b[15]*b[15]==omegav[4,4]
b[4]*b[5]+b[8]*b[9]+b[11]*b[12]+b[13]*b[14]+b[15]*b55==omegav[4,5]

b[5]*b[1]==omegav[5,1]
b[5]*b[2]+b[9]*b[6]==omegav[5,2]
b[5]*b[3]+b[9]*b[7]+b[12]*b[10]==omegav[5,3]
b[5]*b[4]+b[9]*b[8]+b[12]*b[11]+b[14]*b[13]+s55*b[15]==omegav[5,4]
b[5]*b[5]+b[9]*b[9]+b[12]*b[12]+b[14]*b[14]+s55*s55==omegav[5,5]
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any ideas? I am still looking for the answer and would appreciate any comments on this